# Create Matrix with string - Swift

Tags: swift, function, matrix

I try to make matrix function. I want to take number of rows and columns from arguments and show matrix like this:

```
function stars(rows: Int, columns: Int) -> String {
  //I need for loops to create a function body?
}

stars(rows: 5, column: 3)
***
***
***
***
***
```

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Is your question about a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) or about a string describing a rectangular shape of stars?

Comment: You won't stand to learn from asking your homework questions online.

Comment: I know, but sometime I need some tips for solve a problem. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function stars(rows: Int, columns: Int) -> String {
    var str = ""
    for i in 0..<rows{
        for j in 0..<columns{
            str.append("*")
        }
        str.append("\n")
    }
   // print(str)
    return str
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank You very much :) I was very close to solution with my own code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0..<rows{
    for j in 0..<coloumns{
    string.append("*")
    }
  string.append("\n")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it in a playground.
`String(repeating: "*", count: columns)` creates a string that repeats a certain substring, so for example, `String(repeating: "abc", count: 3)` returns `abcabcabc`.
`repeatElement` + `joined` does the same, except that it put separator strings (in this case `\n`) in between the substrings.

```
func stars(rows: Int, columns: Int) -> String {
    let row = String(repeating: "*", count: columns)
    return repeatElement(row, count: rows).joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

Comment: Great! Its work, but this is my first steps in Swift (and programming) and this is hard to understand for me :) Thanks for help, I'll try to find in docs information about this.

Comment: Try it in a playground. `String(repeating: "*", count: columns)` creates a string that repeats a certain substring, so for example, `String(repeating: "abc", count: 3)` returns `"abcabcabc"`. `repeatElement` + `joined` does the same, except that it put separator strings (in this case `"\n"\`) in between the substrings.

Comment: Ok.. now it's look easily :) Thank for explanation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.